# Tomcat 8 running on Linux with remote debug connection ESTABLISHED from Eclipse but breakpoint doesn't stop

Tags: linux, eclipse, windows, remote-debugging

I try to remote debug Tomcat web app which are running in linux 
i started the tomcat with:

```
JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8111,server=y,suspend=n"
```

in the catalina.sh:

```
...
...
...
      # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
    cygwin=false
    darwin=false
    os400=false
    case "`uname`" in
    CYGWIN*) cygwin=true;;
    Darwin*) darwin=true;;
    OS400*) os400=true;;
    esac

    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8111,server=y,suspend=n"

    # resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
    PRG="$0"

    while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
      ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
      link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
      if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
        PRG="$link"
      else
        PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
      fi
    done
...
...
...
```

and then i start tomcat with :

```
Tomcat/bin > catalina.sh jpda start
```

when i do netstat -a | grep 8111  i get :

```
tcp        0      0 *:8111                      *:*                         LISTEN
```

In windows , im using eclipse Version: Mars.1 (4.5.1) 
i configured the remote debug 
[image]

pressed debug , and i see the connection established both in server 
and in windows eclipse like this :

[image]

and in Linux server when i do netstat -a | grep 8111
i see :

```
tcp        0      0  linux:8111             my.pc.ip.66:62285          ESTABLISHED
```

i set allot of break points in eclipse , the source are the same 
but no breakpoints are stooping ... is it a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

The last screenshot is a guarantee that you have connected to your Tomcat. In order to stop on any of your breakpoints you need to exercise the code that you have set a breakpoint in. Usually just using your app will do.

Eclipse sometimes cannot set a breakpoint for some reason. When it does set it successfully a small tick appears on a breakpoint signaling that it is *active*.

[image]

If a particular class did not load yet, or there are some other problems, the breakpoint will not have a tick and will be left *inactive*.

[image]

Ensure that your breakpoints are active. If not, make sure that your project configuration (the one you used to make debug launch config) matches the WAR deployed to Tomcat.

If that does not work, you might have a different compilation options used to build your app deployed to Tomcat, for instance without line numbers. Try setting a breakpoint on method rather than on instruction. If that works, add debug options to compilation step in your build, so that line numbers are also included. That will let you set breakpoints on lines.

Comment: Thanks , in my tomcat it is without this "tick" , the code is the same in both sides . maybe there is some tomcat configuration i missed ??
also when the sources are not the same eclipse throw some error massage

Comment: from my experience  when the sources are not the same eclipse throw some error massage. and in this case no error has Thrown

Comment: What happens when you pause some thread? Are you able to see the sources when clicking through its stack trace?

Comment: i dont see any thing it like they are connected but without connection 
now i installed eclipse in the same linux server and i try to debug the tomcat from within the same server without any luck 
maybe its my eclipse version bug ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with more possible problems. See the last paragraph.

Comment: thanks, in my build the options are with line numbers this is how my ant javac target looks like:
<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" executable="${javacompiler}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">